# What is the ACTION keyword in MySQL

Tags: mysql

What is the `Action` keyword in MySQL? I'm converting a MySQL query into cockroachdb query and the MySQL query I'm seeing is:

```
CREATE TABLE tabDocType Action (
  name varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  creation TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  modified TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  modified_by varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  owner varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  docstatus INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  parent varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  parentfield varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  parenttype varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  idx INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  label varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  group varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  action_type varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  action text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

Also is `Link` also a keyword? It's not in the docs but I'm not quite sure what it's actually doing here:

```
CREATE TABLE `tabDocType Link` (
  `name` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `creation` TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified` TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `owner` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `docstatus` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `parent` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentfield` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `parenttype` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `idx` INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `group` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `link_doctype` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `link_fieldname` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
  KEY `parent` (`parent`),
  KEY `modified` (`modified`)
)
```

From the docs, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html, `ACTION` seems to be a keyword but it doesn't have details on it.

Perhaps they are not keywords at all but serves a different purpose? Thank you.

Comment: It's the Action at the top ```tabDocType Action```

Comment: I personally won't suggest having spaces in table and column names even if it's usable with added backticks and refrain from using reserved keywords; those that have `(R)` appended in the mysql keywords documentation you've linked.

Answer (score 1):

So looks like it's not a keyword, it's part of the table name. Spaces are allowed in a table name as long as the name is in the back tick.

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/can-we-create-a-table-with-a-space-in-name-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with reserved words, create table has no ACTION attribute

As you can read up on the [home page about create table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html)

Still `group` in your create table is a reserved word

```
CREATE TABLE tabDocType  (
  name varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  creation TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  modified TIMESTAMP(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  modified_by varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  owner varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  docstatus INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  parent varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  parentfield varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  parenttype varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  idx INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `label` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `group` varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  action_type varchar(140) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   action text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your literal question, `ACTION` is a reserved word because one of the possible `ON DELETE`/`ON UPDATE` reference option values for a foreign key constraint is `NO ACTION`; see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html